# Binding New Values to User Input Fields

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am sure this question must have been asked before, but I dont seem to find it.

**My Setup:**

- I have two input fields say #inp1 & #inp2
- These two are enclosed inside a form that has a submit button.

**Questions:**

- How can I use jquery or otherwise to 'force' bind new values (other than user input) into these two fields #inp1 and #inp2 upon form submit.
- Will new values be bound before submitting the form? i.e. I would like to see the new values hit the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.val()` method to replace the values of the fields. This will be done before the form is submitted.

```
$("#formid").submit(function() {
    $("#inp1").val("forced value for field 1");
    $("#inp2").val("forced value for field 2");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was waiting to test out your code but it is not working. I still see the old values being hit on the server side. --I am making sure I reference the elements properly.

Comment: Gotcha All I need to do is - $("#inp1").val("forced value for field 1"); and $("#inp2").val("forced value for field 2"); I dont need the $("#formid").submit(function(){..}). I am already handling the onsubmit inside a javascript function.